# dynamic_cast issue with incomplete type

Tags: c++

```
class A 
{
  public:
     virtual void func() {
      cout<<" func():: in class A"<< endl;
     }
     void func1(){
     cout<<"func1():: in class A";
     }
};

class B: public A {
 public:
 void func() {
      cout<<" func():: in class B"<< endl;
     }
     void func1(){
     cout<<"func1():: in class B";
     }
};

int main()
{
 A a;
 A* pa = &a;
 B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
 pb->func1();
 return 0;
}
```

Though `pb` is pointing to an incomplete type and `dynamic_cast` will return `null`.
But why it is not crashing in this scenario?

Comment: *undefined behavior* is **undefined** *behavior*, there's nothing more to say about it really.

Comment: I can not see any inccomplete type class.

Comment: If you were trying to access member data in func1 it would certainly crash.

Comment: An incomplete type is one that has only been declared but not defined. Like `class X;`. What you have is simply dereferencing a null pointer, because the `dynamic_cast` failed and you didn't check the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `func1` in your `B` class doesn't access any member variables (or virtual functions) it doesn't use the implicit `this` pointer and therefore, in this case, does not crash.

Note that this is **undefined behaviour** so it may crash (or do something unexpected) in a different compiler (or compiler version) so don't depend on this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `A *` that is pointing to an instance of `A`, not `A *` that is actually pointing to an instance of `B`. That is why `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer of type `B *`, it is not related to these being incomplete types or anything (in the linked code, both `A` and `B` are complete types), and thus this is defined behaviour for `dynamic_cast`. However after that a null pointer is accessed; a clever compile can know that `dynamic_cast` can fail at that point and the `pb->func1();` can do anything including *not* causing a null pointer exception or anything at all, or even calling the `pb1->func`  on something that is not `B`.

---

An example with an incomplete type would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void func() {
        cout << "func():: in class A" << endl;
    }
    void func1(){
        cout<< "func1():: in class A";
    }
};

class B;

int main() {
    A a;
    A* pa = &a;
    B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you compile this with G++, you get

```
y.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
y.cc:20:32: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘pa’ (of type ‘class A*’) to 
     type ‘class B*’ (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)
     B* pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
```

that is all sane C++ compilers will reject such code.

Comment: Thanks Anitti for figuring out , I meant to say pb points to an incomplete type as in gdb when i had tried
(gdb) p *pB
$3 = <incomplete type>
Correct me if I am wrong and thanks for replying on my doubt, i got the point :)